# Getting NoTestsRemainException when I try to run my junits

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, junit4

I am new to junits. When I try to run my testsuite it is giving me this error. I googled but didn't get any answer. Posting the stacktrace.

```
org.junit.runner.manipulation.NoTestsRemainException
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:327)
at org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.<init>(Categories.java:151)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:35)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here is the testsuite which I am trying to run.

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(DCCTests.class)
@SuiteClasses({ AllTests.class })
public class DealerCommandCenterTestsSuite {

}
```

Comment: what is the version of your JUnit? And how are you running the tests - e.g. ant, maven, eclipse ?

Comment: I think non of your tests are in the category DCCTests, so the runner finds no tests left after applying the filter. To confirm, can you please put your test sample here?

Comment: @Pat: I am running using eclipse.

Comment: @Girish: No there are many tests in DCCTests.

Comment: @Prasad - and ur JUnit version?

Comment: @Pat: Version is 4.10

Answer (score 1):

I discussed a similar problem in [What is Junit trying to tell me when it throws a "NoTestsRemainException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587994/what-is-junit-trying-to-tell-me-when-it-throws-a-notestsremainexception), the cause for me was an outdated JUnit jar of version 3.8 being loaded instead of the required JUnit 4.11.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example for @Category (The example is from Java Doc). It works with my JUnit 4.11

org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories

```
public interface FastTests {
 }

 public interface SlowTests {
 }

 public static class A {
    @Test
    public void a() {
        fail();
    }

    @Category(SlowTests.class)
    @Test
    public void b() {
    }
 }

 @Category( { SlowTests.class, FastTests.class })
 public static class B {
    @Test
    public void c() {

    }
 }

 @RunWith(Categories.class)
 @IncludeCategory(SlowTests.class)
 @SuiteClasses( { A.class, B.class })
 // Note that Categories is a kind of Suite
 public static class SlowTestSuite {
 }
```

A main to call:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Result result  = JUnitCore.runClasses(SlowTestSuite.class);

        /** Check results **/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is technically correct for your sample, but very misleading.

org.junit.runners.AllTests.class is not a valid parameter for @SuiteClasses (it is meant to be a JUnit 3.8 adapter) , so that the Categories runner discards it internally and then reports it has "no remaining tests" to run.

I suppose the incomplete error handling goes with the "experimental" part of the Java package for Categories, which is now deprecated by the new @Tag annotation in JUnit 5.

If you need to dynamically include all tests contained in classes in the classpath, try this thread: [How do I Dynamically create a Test Suite in JUnit 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but could be worth for someone

1. Make sure you are using proper versions of libs. In my case `junit-4.13.2`, JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform 1.9.2 + JUnit Jupiter 5.9.2 + JUnit Vintage 5.9.2
2. Annotation `@Test` is imported using `org.junit.Test`, not a `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`
3. Make all tests methods and class public